# PAYPAL IPN C# Routing Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal-ipn

I am trying to implement Paypal IPN in C# using the coding sample [paypal_ipn_mvc.cs](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/C%23/paypal_ipn_mvc.cs)

I use routing attributes and I altered the code as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("paypalipn/", Name = "PayPalIPN")]               
public HttpStatusCodeResult PayPalIPN()
{
    //Store the IPN received from PayPal
    LogRequest(Request);

    //Fire and forget verification task
    Task.Run(() => VerifyTask(Request));

    //Reply back a 200 code
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

At first it seemed to work okay and I was able to use the [Paypal IPN Simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSimulator/) a few times before it stopped.

When using the URL on my local dev machine I get this error:

> No matching action was found on controller 'foo.PayPalController'. This can happen when a controller uses RouteAttribute for routing, but no action on that controller matches the request.

If I remove the Routing Attribute I get:

> The controller for path '/paypalipn/' was not found or does not implement IController.

I tried creating an empty ActionResult without the [HttpPost] but because I have no parameters in the post I cannot.

1. Has anyone had a similar issue and resolved it?
2. There are very few C# MVC examples of the IPN. Those that I have found either do not work or are out of date in regards to the new security protocols. Does anyone have a sure fire example I might have missed?
3. The example data models all seem to be different. The example provided [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) differed greatly from the data content from the IPN Simulator. When I asked a friend to send an example of their IPN from their live app it differed again. Seems I have found 3 different data structures without even looking. Is there a standard?

Comment: See [TLS 1.2 and HTTP/1.1 Upgrade](https://www.paypal.com/au/webapps/mpp/tls-http-upgrade)

Comment: What controller is that method in?

Comment: Controller is PayPalController : Controller

Comment: I have added ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; to the code